# Is json.parse and json.stringify are opposite?

Tags: javascript, json, html, html5-canvas

I am working with html5 canvas. I have following js code

```
var c2 = document.getElementById("imageView");
var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.strokeRect(10,10, 50, 50);//sample image

var img = ctx2.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 400);
data=JSON.stringify(img)

abc=JSON.parse(data)
imgcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
imgcanvas.id     = 'image';
imgcanvas.width  = 300;
imgcanvas.height = 400;
container.appendChild(imgcanvas);
var c = document.getElementById("image");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.putImageData(abc, 0, 0);
```

I am expecting same image as in canvas imageview. But i dont get it..

Comment: `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` are opposite only if the object fed to `stringify` was completely JSON serializable. (They are always opposite from the other direction)

Answer (score 1):

When you stringify the object, the result is an object notation meaning the loss of its prototype - ImageData. Again parsing it will give a JSON object with prototype as "Object" object. Thus you will not get the image as desired.

Now in case you have to follow stringify route:

```
1. Create a new object of type ImageData by : var imgData = ctx.createImageData(100,100); //ctx is the context
2. iterate over all the keys of object returned by result of JSON.parse and set each of imgData.data[i] = theobject.data[key];
```

3. Now use this imgData object for new image.

Hope it helps!